# Почему Python распознает вводные числа как str?

Tags: python

Мне нужно ввести число, но возвращаеттся не тот тип данных:

```python
i = input()
print(type(i))
```

Вывод:

> <class 'str'>

Как получить не строку, а целое число?

Comment: Ну инпут же читает строку, а как эту строку потом интерпретировать  - ваше дело. Если там должно быть целое число, приведите к int

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

Answer (score 2):

Согласно документации, `input()` всегда  возвращает введённую строку в виде `str`. Чтобы получить число (например, `int`), нужно привести переменную к необходимому типу:

```
n = int(input())
print(type(n))
```

> <class 'int'>

Answer (score 0):

Потому что `input` всегда в любом случае возвращает строку